# Recyler view initial position

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using `recylerview` to display vertical list of data but when i open my app it is scrolled to last item automatically.How do i change default position of `recyclerview`?

Comment: Set setStackFromEnd=false or setReverseLayout=false

Comment: Thanks it was set to true :)

Comment: is it working for you ?

Comment: yes reverse layout was set to true i changed it to false now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should set **setStackFromEnd=false** or **setReverseLayout=false**

And are you sure that you don't set **scrollToPosition(list.size())**?

Comment: Can u add me on fb it will be great help as sometimes there are doubts which u can't ask on stackoverflow?

Comment: Sorry i am Employee :)

Comment: Yes i know i won't disturb you and will discuss when most needed

Comment: Related to designing techniques and approach